# ビデオファイル(MPEG4 .MP4)内の、フレーム レート情報（のみ）を書き換える方法

Tags: mp4

#### 目的

誤ったフレーム レートが記録されているビデオファイルがある(.MP4 ファイル）。
ファイル内のフレーム レート情報のみを書き換えて、正しい速度で再生したい。

OS: Windows
言語: C# or python で処理したい

#### やってみたこと

OpenCV + Python

```py
src = VideoCapture('間違ったFPS.mp4') 
dst = VideoWriter('修正した.mp4' , 正しいFPS)
```

`src.read` と `dst.write` でコピーし、新しく、正しいFPSのファイルを作成することはできた。

#### 上記の問題点

ビデオ ファイル内全フレームのコピーを行っているので時間がかかる。

#### 知りたいこと

”間違ったFPS.mp4”ファイル内のフレーム レート情報を書き換えられないか？
OpenCVの `VideoCapture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS , 30.0)` 的なことがしたい。

もしかしたら、そもそもMPEG4ファイルの仕組み上、フレーム レートのみを書き換えても
意味をなさないのかもしれない。

Comment: 試していませんが、Ffmpeg での例です。 [【ffmpeg】fps情報がおかしい動画ファイルの修正 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/daemokra/items/817ab1074a12f1f99206)